# Move timezone field in user/%/edit field

Tags: users, forms, theming

I want to move timezone field in `user/%/edit` form. I have used`$form['#weight']` in `hook_form_alter()` and `$page['#weight']` in `hook_page_alter()`, but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next snippet should work

```
<?php

function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_profile_form') {
    $form['#after_build'][] = 'MYMODULE_user_profile_form_pre_render';
  }
}

function MYMODULE_user_profile_form_pre_render($form) {
  $form['timezone']['#weight'] = -10;
  return $form;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but not working

Comment: I can able to move all fields except this.

Comment: I have updated code

Comment: I have changed the weight but I can't move the field. See [this screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gH3an.png).

Comment: This also not working

Comment: I tested this code on my site and it works fine. Could you please try to clear caches?